# Display event details from google calendar on mouseover

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to display event details on mouseover in fullcalendar instead of clicking on it.
Here's my code so far:

$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
        'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/8msdika8k0vtf797v81rq4ot4%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
        ],
        eventClick: [function(event) {
        if (event.url) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    ],
    eventMouseover :function(event, jsEvent, view) 
        {

        },


    })

});

What do i add inside the eventmouseover function so that it displays event details from my google calendar?  Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer and comments to the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15006685/624479). The last comment to the answer has a JsFiddle that shows details (you'll have to style / configure yourself).

If you would consider a popup, then look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944238/624479).